# Getting consecutive elements and remove them

Tags: c++

I have an array of indices of triangles, basically a std::vector 
I have three numbers that I want to remove by value, but they must be consecutive.

I tried to use the code below:

```
updatedIndices.erase(std::remove(updatedIndices.begin(), updatedIndices.end(), u1), updatedIndices.end());

updatedIndices.erase(std::remove(updatedIndices.begin(), updatedIndices.end(), u2), updatedIndices.end());

updatedIndices.erase(std::remove(updatedIndices.begin(), updatedIndices.end(), u3), updatedIndices.end());
```

where `u1`, `u2`, `u3` are the three value numbers that needs to be removed. They must be consecutive in the array.
Is there a fast stl approach to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to search for a specific sequence of consecutive values, use `std::search`.

```
SomeType valuesToFind[3] = {u1, u2, u3};
auto p = std::search(
    std::begin(updatedIndices), std::end(updatedIndices),
    std::begin(valuesToFind), std::end(valuesToFind));

if (p != std::end(updatedIndices)) {
    updatedIndices.erase(p, p + 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use `std::find` to find the `u1`, check if other two elements follow using the `std::next` function and erase a range:

```
int u1 = 2;
int u2 = 8;
int u3 = 4;
std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 8, 4, 9 };
auto resultit = std::find(std::begin(v), std::end(v), u1);
if (resultit != std::end(v)) {
    if (*std::next(resultit) == u2 && *std::next(resultit, 2) == u3) {
        v.erase(resultit, resultit + 3);
    }
}
```